# Pandas Resample week interval

Tags: pandas, datetime

I am trying use to resample for a `weekly interval` which starts on `monday`. I want to find out how many approved per week.

```
status       epoch           date                   status_binary
Approved    1642310487671   2022-01-16 13:21:27.671     1
Approved    1642311524618   2022-01-16 13:38:44.618     1
Approved    1642312050595   2022-01-16 13:47:30.595     1
Approved    1642312400462   2022-01-16 13:53:20.462     1
```

When I use the resample for as below. the `2022-01-16` gets group into `2022-01-17`.
It should be grouped into week of start `2022-01-10`

I tried all the possible `close`, `origin`, but couldnt get the wanted output

```
df.resample('W-MON', on="date", closed='left', origin="start")['status_binary'].sum()
```

Output from above code. Please advise how can I get the wanted output of `2022-01-10 sum=4.`

```
               sum
2022-01-17      4
2022-01-24      0
2022-01-31      0
```

Comment: your example is not reproducible, could you please update?

Comment: alright, i have updated. please help. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I have found it it by using `closed = "left" , label = "left"`